# btn class does not create space in between buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my code in my app. all the bootstrap class working in this app but in case of the `btn` class it is not giving default `margin` between. I tried the code on codepen it gives `margin` but on my app the `margin` is not there. Buttons stay together.

What could be a possible issue?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
          <label for="name">Ingredient name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
          <label for="amount">Amount</label>
          <input type="number" id="amount" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You clearly have other CSS being loaded somewhere over-riding the bootstrap css for the "button"

Comment: I checked it there is not any other css properties i used. Could it it be in the bootstrap file which i installed in my project has some flaws

Comment: I thought you have use any other external or internal css and he is overwrite the bootstrap default css property. If you share your url then i find your bug.

Comment: You must add a style for your .btn class. please check your style file and remove margin property from the style

Comment: Hey, I am doing the same course and I have the same issue, did you find the why?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed us the result - I can't tell what the problem is. I see a space in the code below - I just copied your code. If you want to add more margin, just add some of the css code below into your code.

```
.btn {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
          <label for="name">Ingredient name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
          <label for="amount">Amount</label>
          <input type="number" id="amount" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked with applying the margin attribute to .btn class. But why the btn clas automatically not giving margin on my project? Could it be due to any flaw while  installing bootstrap to my project?

Comment: btn normally doesn't add any margin - It's no error, it's just the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight change in Angular 6 and later that removes the 4px gaps and other white spaces by default. To enable this functionality you can wrap up the buttons in another div with class btn-toolbar. like for your code you can simply write

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
</div>
```